# Jquery comparing object

Tags: jquery

```
var videoinfo = [{
    "startdatetime":"2014-12-21 00:23:14",
    "totalsecondrun":"5",
    "videolist":[
        {
            "videoid":"uoSDF234",
            "second":"10"
        },
        {
            "videoid":"0apq3ss",
            "second":"14"
        }
    ]
}];
```

I need a function to calculate current video and second, but so far I don't have any idea how to start.

1. use `totalsecondrun` to find currently playing which video
2. base on `totalsecondrun` is between which video now.
3. exmaple: `totalsecondrun:"5"`, `5` so should be the first video, function return `videoid` and `second` (`totalsecondrun:"5"` - first video `second` = video stopped `second`)
4. example: `totalsecondrun:"12"`, `12` is more than first video, so now it should be second video, so function return `videoid` and `second` too.

Anyone can suggest me what should I do ?

Comment: can you be more clear . seems you already have solution to your problem . what you are not able to do ?

Comment: @shifu dont know how to write ...

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing, apart from the logic? Are you asking how to access values from the JSON?

Comment: @surajck how to compare and match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this is what you want to do .

```
var videoinfo = [{
        "startdatetime":"2014-12-21 00:23:14",
        "totalsecondrun":"5",
        "videolist":[
            {
                "videoid":"uoSDF234",
                "second":"10"
            },
            {
                "videoid":"0apq3ss",
                "second":"14"
            }
        ]
    }];
    getVedioID();
    function getVedioID(){
        var sum = 0;
        var list = videoinfo[0].videolist;
        for(var i=0 ; i<list.length ; ++i){
            sum+=parseInt(list[i].second);
            if(sum > parseInt(videoinfo[0].totalsecondrun)){
                var ans = {};
                ans['curr'] = list[i].videoid;
                ans['next'] = list[i+1].videoid;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: if I change the `totalsecondrun` to `11` mean more than first video `second` it will error

Comment: OK I have modify some of your code to what I expected so far, now my problem only left one. `second` part , if i set `totalsecondrun` is `5` the `ans` should give me the rest `5` also. if i set `totalsecondrun` to `11` it should give me the `13`

Comment: i just showed how to handle json for your case . error handling hope you can do self.

Comment: OK, I have done what I want because of your suggestion code, I tried to keep modify what I need, finally I did ! Thanks you so much !